ScriptableObjects not appearing in list
I have a list(editor dropdown) made for GameObjects, which is a list of two. My script rotates between the two, and that works just fine. I tried the same thing with ScriptableObjects and it doesn't work. I select the objects in the editor, which works, but then when I playtest, both values go to None.
All the junk at the bottom is floats and bools.
public int totalWeapons = 2;
int currentWeaponIndex;
public GameObject[] weapons;
public Weapons[] weaponsData;
public GameObject currentWeaponGO;
GameObject weaponHolder;

    private void Awake()
{
    weapons = new GameObject[totalWeapons];
    weaponsData = new Weapons[totalWeapons];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < totalWeapons; i++)
    {
        weapons[i] = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        weapons[i] .SetActive(false);
    }
    weapons [0].SetActive(true);
    currentWeaponGO = weapons[0];

    currentWeaponIndex = 0;
    refreshWeapon();
    currentAmmo = currentWeapon.maxAmmoCapacity;
    weaponHolder = this.GetComponent<GameObject>();

}




private void Update()
{
    scroll();
}

void scroll()
{
    if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f && currentWeaponIndex < totalWeapons -1)
    {
        currentWeapon = weaponsData[1];

        weapons[currentWeaponIndex].SetActive(false);
        currentWeaponIndex += 1;
        weapons[currentWeaponIndex].SetActive(true);
        refreshWeapon();
    }

    if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f && currentWeaponIndex > 0)
    {
        weapons[currentWeaponIndex].SetActive(false);
        currentWeaponIndex -= 1;
        weapons[currentWeaponIndex].SetActive(true);
        refreshWeapon();
    }

}
void refreshWeapon()
{
    cooldown = currentWeapon.timeBetweenShots;
    maxAmmo = currentWeapon.maxAmmoCapacity;
    maxRange = currentWeapon.Range;
    bulletSpread = currentWeapon.spread;
    pelletAmount = currentWeapon.projectileAmountPerShot;
    hitscanDamage = currentWeapon.HsDamage;
    knockBack = currentWeapon.knockBack;
    knockBackForce = currentWeapon.knockBackForce;
    ammoType = currentWeapon.ammoType;
}


what "int" ? Please provide [mcve] as theres a lot of variables, and no idea what any of them are, whats "none" ?

theres still a ton missing, how are you populating weapondata, that you seem to use later, "currentWeapon = weaponsData[1];" because in awake you obliterate anything that was in it

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You didn't provide this information, but I can guess that Weapons is your ScriptableObject. If that's correct, the following happens:

you have your Inspector field public Weapons[] weaponsData; where you set the data
then, in Awake, you overwrite the data you set with weaponsData = new Weapons[totalWeapons];, which results in weaponsData containing an array of null's, which is displayed as None in Inspector.


Short answer
Just remove this line: weaponsData = new Weapons[totalWeapons];

Long answer
Values you set in Inspector are serialized (stored to drive as part of your project) by Unity. When the game is run, Unity first reads these values from the drive and then calls Awake.
Knowing that, you can also avoid overwriting the weapons array:
private void Awake() 
{
    weapons[0].SetActive(true);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < totalWeapons; i++)
    {
        weapons[i].SetActive(false);
    }
    
    currentWeaponGO = weapons[0];

    currentWeaponIndex = 0;
    refreshWeapon();
    currentAmmo = currentWeapon.maxAmmoCapacity;
    weaponHolder = this.GetComponent<GameObject>();
}

But what if you want to do everything in code, not in Inspector? You need to populate your weaponsData array alongside the weapons array. An easy way is this:
    for (int i = 0; i < totalWeapons; i++)
    {
        weapons[i] = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        weapons[i] .SetActive(false);

        weaponsData[i] = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Weapons>();
    }

    weapons[0].SetActive(true);

but this creates new instances of ScriptableObjects not using those stored in your project.
To use the stored ScriptableObject assets you need to move them to the Resources folder (and create one if it doens't exist) and then load them by the path in that folder. Let's say, you moved your ScriptableObject assets to "Assets/Resources/Weapons" folder and they are named "Weapons1" and "Weapons2", tehn you can load them like this:
    for (int i = 0; i < totalWeapons; i++)
    {
        weapons[i] = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        weapons[i] .SetActive(false);

        weaponsData[i] = Resources.Load<Weapons>("Weapons/Weapons" + i);
    }
    
    weapons[0].SetActive(true);

